# complex number input by clicking on the complex plane

Tags: python, tkinter, real-time

I've written a Python code which requires a complex number as the only input.
At the moment the user is required to type the number through a Tkinter entry widget and everything is working fine, but I'd rather have another window with a portion of complex plane where the user could click to select the complex value.
Also, the program uses this number to do several things and shows 4 output pictures (on 4 different canvas) depending on that number. The best thing would be if the user could even click and scroll the mouse pointer on the complex plane to get the software plot in real time, as the complex parameter varies through the plane.

Is there an easy way to do this without using classes? 
I'm a mathematician, not a programmer, so I apologise if my question is too basic.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a general tip, don't use canvases JUST for pictures. If you're only going to have a picture in the widget, I recommend a label.

Comment: Sorry I was not very precise. The "picture" is actually a collection of geometrical items created by the methods (is this the right name?) create_oval, create_line and so on. That's why I used canvases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `canvas` or a `label` for the picture of the complex plane, and bind the `<Button-1>` and `<B1-Motion>` events to callback functions that handle mouse-clicks and mouse-dragging, respectively. These callback functions will be passed a parameter that holds the `x` and `y` coordinates of the mouse cursor, which you can normalize, round, and use to define a complex number.

See [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) for more details on event binding and handling.